# In Figma how do I match the radius of a round square to that of a circle?

Tags: figma

In Figma how do I match the radius of a round square to that of a circle? I am finding this very difficult to achieve, google brings up nothing unless I am searching the wrong keywords? Is there a mathematical term for this? Is there a plugin that can achieve this? [image]

As you can see from the above image its really hard to get it 100% matching although ideally, I would prefer the circle to be smaller, where making it smaller makes it even more challenging to achieve?

Comment: Might have some downsides, but if you want a 100% perfect match: 4 circles and a square to connect them

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Basically what Billy did in his answer, except copy the circle to all corners, make the rectangle radius a hair smaller than the circle's radius. Then union the shapes into one and flatten it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the circle to select it. Take a note of the width or height (note that both should be the same for a perfect circle). This will be the same as the diameter of the circle
2. Divide the diameter by 2 to calculate the radius
3. This step is not necessary, but you can click and drag the circle so it snaps to the corner of the rectangle, so you can check the result if you want
4. Select the rectangle, and in the Design tab, set the corner radius you calculated in step 2.

[image]